# WordPress 3.2 - Problem with WYSIWYG editors in a custom post type?

Tags: posts, wysiwyg, customization

I'm using this class http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html to create custom meta-box in which it contains some WYSIWYG editors. It works fine until I upgraded my WP to 3.2. The WYSIWYG editors are now have white text background and all tinyMCE buttons are gone!

I guess they've changed quite a lot of things in TinyMCE editor in this 3.2 version to accommodate the "full screen editing" stuff. Bad for me though, it destroys my custom metabox... And there is no documents about this change, at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [here](http://dannyvankooten.com/450/tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-in-wordpress-plugin/), add this to your functions.php

```
add_action("admin_head","myplugin_load_tiny_mce");

function myplugin_load_tiny_mce() {

wp_tiny_mce( false ); // true gives you a stripped down version of the editor

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a change but an upgrade to TinyMCE included with WordPress.

Your best bet is to contact the author of the script to see if he'll update it to work with 3.2.

Comment: On the website itself there is indeed a long thread where this problem has been mentioned a couple of times already. I also have contacted Rilwis (the developer) to ask if there is a solution. Will post back as soon as I hear sth.